# Role of functional equations in current panorama of pure mathematics

Tags: analysis, reference-request, soft-question, functional-equations, big-picture

It seems that currently functional equations are greatly explored as a research field. I would like to know what is the importance and role of such a field in the panorama of the current development of pure mathematics (also in relation to other branches).

Comment: From my youth, when I dealt with functional equations at math competitions, I still have a humble, but experienced and opposite opinion: in most cases they are not deep and can be easily solved by some manipulations. Exclusions are very rare (see, for instance, [Discrete Liouville's Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/a-stronger-version-of-discrete-liouvilles-theorem)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) for the Riemann Zeta Function and its [generalizations](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/functional-equation/) to $L$ functions is very important.

According to the [Bohr-Mollerup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) theorem, a function $f$ which satisifes $f(1)=1$, $f(x+1)=xf(x)$ for $x>0$ and is logarithmically convex must be the Gamma function $\Gamma(x)$.

[Somos Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence) are a set of sequence recurrence relations which seem to have profound relations to Jacobi theta functions, [aztec diamonds](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0402452.pdf) and [cluster algebras](http://www.math.umn.edu/~musiker/uthesis.pdf). They sometimes inexplicably produce integer valued sequences.  Specifically, the octohedral recurrence:

$$f(n,i,j)f(n-2,i,j)=f(n-1,i-1,j)f(n-1,i+1,j)+f(n-1,i,j-1)f(n-1,i,j+1),$$

with appropriate boundary conditions comes up in a lot of places, one being Dodgson (Lewis Carroll) Condensation for determinants . Generalizations of this are sometimes called [T-Systems](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0095v1.pdf).

Comment: For Somos sequences, the word "bizarre" is not what I would use. They came to me after years of studying addition theorems of Jacobi theta functions. They exhibit simple examples of the important "Laurent phenomenon".

Comment: @Somos: Point taken! I really only meant to emphasize the "profound" part, as the sequences seem to be appearing more and more in tiling combinatorics and integrable systems.